# Extra argument 'selector' in call - NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

Tags: timer, swift, nstimer

I have the following line of code:

```
changeColour = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(TIMES, target: self, selector: "changeColourOfPage", repeats: true)
```

but it gives the error "Extra argument 'selector' in call"

when I change the `TIMES` variable to a number like `1.0`, it works fine. The variable `TIMES` is set to `1.0`.

Is this just a glitch, or am I being stupid about something?
I need to use it to run a method at random intervals.

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the userInfo argument. Try this:

**Swift 2**

```
let TIMES = 1.0
var changeColour = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(TIMES, target: self, selector: "restart", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
let TIMES = 1.0
var changeColour = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TIMES, target: self, selector: #selector(restart), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: I think @connor is right that this is your problem. Can you elaborate on where that breakpoint is?

Answer (score 25):

Just had this same issue.  For me the problem was that I was passing a time interval as a Float not a Double.  Simple fix was (using the code from the original post):

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(TIMES), target: self, selector: Selector("changeColourOfPage"), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)
```

I had the same error message and once I cast the time as a Double it worked fine.  Hope that helps someone!